# Define global variables in parrent view and use them in partial views in asp core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, global-variables

I have a `.cshtml` file that has a model.

```
@model MainModel
```

It calls different partials as below:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialOne", partialOneModel)
```

but in partials, I need the mainModel, too. I checked it that if I use ViewBag for read the `MainModel` it works. (as mentioned in stack-over-flow before)
in main.cshtml:

```
ViewBag.MyMainModel= Model;
```

and in _PartialOne.cshtml:

```
<div>
@ViewBag.MyMainModel.CustomerId
</div>
```

But I want to know that, IS it possible to define a variable that works as **global** that I can define it once in main.cshtml and use it in partials?
If yes, how?
I checked the usual way for define the variable and it not works:
in main.cshtml:

```
var mainModel=Model;
```

and in _PartialOne.cshtml:

```
 <div>
    @mainModel
 </div>
```

The Error:

```
The name 'mainModel' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: Instead of this why cant you have child parent relation between two models? And pass main model as well in partial and use things which you like?

Comment: Then I can't use asp-for for validation in child

Comment: Can you override TagHelper? Also there is one more option of passing ViewDataDictionary to partial. Please check.